# How can I consolidate this Swift snippet?

Tags: swift

My code smells. Please help improve this snippet in Swift5:

```
sectionItems = [[infos[0].infoText ?? "uhoh0"],  [infos[1].infoText ?? "uhoh0"],  [infos[2].infoText ?? "uhoh2"],  [infos[3].infoText ?? "uhoh3"],  [infos[4].infoText ?? "uhoh4"],  [infos[5].infoText ?? "uhoh5"],  [infos[6].infoText ?? "uhoh6"],  [infos[7].infoText ?? "uhoh7"],  [infos[8].infoText ?? "uhoh8"],  [infos[9].infoText ?? "uhoh9"]]
```

Comment: The expression `infos[0].infoText` (or `infos[any_index]`, for that matter) is dangerous, since if `infos` is empty, it will crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are essentially iterating over your `infos` array and then pulling out the `infoText` from it and then replacing it with "uhoh0" if it isn't there.

And then placing that item into an array (which seems odd but...)

So...

```
let sectionItems = infos
    .enumerated()
    .map { (index, o) in [o.infoText ?? "uhoh\(index)"] }
```

Would do the same thing I think.

But I'd be interested to hear why you are doing this and what the rest of the code is.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be `uhoh0` in all of them, I believe it's `uhoh{index}` and there's a typo for the second value.

Comment: @FogMeister, thanks for the code. I have a project that needs an info page. I have the data for the page in a Json file that I'm importing to a CodeData object graph. The info page is a tableview of the explanations. I want to keep the help information separate from the app.

Comment: You missed the fact that the OP wants to default to "uhoh0" for the item at index 0, "uhoh1" for index 1, etc. You should probably map `infos.enumerated()` instead, and build the result by concatenating "uhoh" with the index value.

Comment: @DuncanC ah yeah, I looked at the first two and didn’t see the pattern. My bad.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I’ve updated the code now so it will add the index in.